# rga ( R Google Analytics) query contains sampled data?

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I'm using [rga](https://github.com/skardhamar/rga) package to get data from Google Anlytics API with R.

As the query data range is huge and have a lot of data I'm using the BATCH = TRUE and WALK=TRUE features to get de data day by day to avoid sampling. Despite of this, I'm not sure if it contains sampled data beacuse I can't find any opotion / message that say so.

Comment: Seems `walk = TRUE` didn't works as expected. Yo can try [this](https://github.com/artemklevtsov/RGA/blob/master/vignettes/reporting-api.Rmd#sampled-data) tip from the RGA package docs.

Comment: Why do you say is not working as expected? For mi is working fine this option, the only problem is that the only way to know if that day's query has sampled data is a message printed in the console, despite this, all is working perfectly. There is not  a programmatic way to detect it. (I would not like to change the source code of rga)